# Android : Making Lockscreen Opaque

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'd like to modify lockscreen to make it opaque in Android 4.x for some experimental purposes.
I know there are plenty of questions about lockscreen and lots suggestions to write a new application from scratch.
Those won't work for me. I want to work with existing android source, modify and recompile it.

Any thoughts/suggestions???

Comment: To work with the 'existing android source, modify and recompile it', you would have to be capable of flashing your own firmware after having modified the OS.  Is this something you're prepared to do? Or do you want to write your own application, **USING** the android source?

Comment: @JRaymond, '>Is this something you're prepared to do?' - Yes this is what I like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a big undertaking, but you might start [here](http://code.google.com/p/custom-rom-creator-studio/wiki/QuickStartupGuide), or, more in depth, at the android source repository [here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html), if you're looking to do something much more in depth.

As for where in the source to look, the KeyGuard (which is the real name) stuff is under
`/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/` for the layout files and `/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/` for the Java source.

Good luck!